# Redirect to the same URL sans query parameters using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routes, query-string

I load the application URL for the password reset as follows:

http://localhost/myapp/#/login?resetcode=944F1WO71BU32

After the successful reset, I want to redirect to the login component which is on the same page, but the URL should be:
http://localhost/myapp/#/login

I tried using `$window.location.reload();` and `$location.path('/my/path').search({});` but that didn't work. It still shows the url with the query string.

```
  vm.resetpassword = function () {
        $scope.errorMessage = '';
        var changePasswordModel = new SetPasswordModel();
        changePasswordModel.resetcode = $route.current.params.resetcode;
        changePasswordModel.newpassword = vm.password;
        changePasswordModel.confirmpassword = vm.retypepassword;
        if (vm.password.length >= 8 && common.isPasswordValid(vm.password)) 
        {
            security.resetPassword(changePasswordModel)
                .then(function () {
                    $scope.message = "Updating Password...";
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $location.search({});
                    }, 3000);
                }, function (err) {
                    $scope.errorMessage = err.ModelState.Error[0];
                });
        } else {
            $scope.showPasswordPolicy = true;
        }
    };
```

Solution:

```
    var url = $location.search({});
    window.location.href = url.absUrl();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
window.location.href="your path";
```

Comment: it didn't work. I added the code for the reset function.

Comment: actually, this might have worked - but when I gave the path as window.location.href=$location.path(), it redirects to localhost/login but it should be localhost/myapp/#/login

Comment: in place of $location.path() directly give your path like myapp/login/...html try with  this it may be work..

Comment: var url = $location.search({});
 window.location.href = url.absUrl();

Answer (score 0):

To remove URL parameters use

```
$location.url($location.path());
```

Or you can simply use this for removing all params

```
$location.search({});
```

Comment: it didn't work. I added the code for the reset function.